# c# Json retornando barra invertida

Tags: c#, json, serialização, desserialização

Sou novo em web, estou tentando retornar um json porem ele vem com barras assim:

`{\"NomeUsuario\":\"TESTE\",\"TelefoneUsuario\":\"1111111111\"}`

Como faço para ele ficar assim:

`{"NomeUsuario":"TESTE","TelefoneUsuario":"1111111111"}`

Tenho a classe pessoa:

```
[DataContract]
public class Pessoa
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string TelefoneUsuario { get; set; }
}
```

Método

```
 public string FiltradoPorPessoa(string Nome, string Variavel)
    {
        DataTable Dtconsulta = new DataTable();
        Pessoa retorno = null;

        Sql = " SELECT  NomeUsuario, TelefoneUsuario";
        Sql += " FROM Cadastro.DTUsuario";
        Sql += " WHERE NomeUsuario = '" + Nome.ToUpper() + "' AND SenhaUsuario = '" + GeraHash(Variavel.ToUpper()) + "'";

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn);
        conn.Open();

        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);

        if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Pessoa p = new Pessoa();

            DataTableReader DtConsultaReader = dataTable.CreateDataReader();
            while (DtConsultaReader.Read())
            { 
                p.Nome  = DtConsultaReader["NomeUsuario"].ToString();
                p.TelefoneUsuario = DtConsultaReader["TelefoneUsuario"].ToString();
            }
            DtConsultaReader.Close();
            conn.Close();

            var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(p);

            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Pessoa));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
            retorno = (Pessoa)ser.ReadObject(ms);  
        }
        return retorno;     
    }
```

E um método que retorna um datatable, copio esse para um datareader, o que estou fazendo de errado, não consigo retornar a string?

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'teste15_04.Pessoa' to 'string' dessa maneira {"NomeUsuario":"TESTE","TelefoneUsuario":"1111111111"}

Comment: `json.Replace("\", "");`?

Comment: Primeiro, você entende o significado de `\"` na string?

Comment: Segundo, você entende o significado de \" na string?

Comment: Eu vi por cima que é um caractere de escape tem relação com a aspas dupla! porém se usar repace ele tira todas as aspas da string.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que está tentando fazer no seu método, mas no final dele você tenta retornar um `objeto` `Pessoa` sendo que o método retorna `string`

Answer (score 2):

Essa barra só é visível em debug mode, se você colocar para imprimir
o conteúdo dessa variável que contém a string JSON, vai sair sem a barra.

Para trabalhar com JSON, te aconselho a usar o Newtonsoft.Json, é bem mais utilizado e tem bem mais documento de como se trabalhar com ele, por exemplo para deserializar um JSON em um objeto é assim:

```
var objeto = JsonConvert.Deserialize<SeuObjeto>(stringJson);
```

e para pegar um objeto e gerar uma string JSON, é assim:

```
var json = JsonConvert.Serialize<TypeOf(SeuObjeto)>(seuObjeto);
```